mt3608 in-rush current
I have been testing MT3608 based DC-DC step-up converter from Ebay. These boards are popular, extremely simple and implement just the basic circuit from the IC datasheet.

Reverse engineered circuit is identical to the datasheet typical application circuit.

IC datasheet boasts a soft start feature. Quote from the datasheet:

Internal soft-start results in small inrush current and
extends battery life.

However I noticed that these boards often have difficulties starting unless the supply is able to output >4A. IC can lockup and just sink current, at least on a bench supply that drops the voltage to limit current. While testing I've been using 15V Vout setting and 47 Ohm resistor load. Input voltage 7V.
Is this expected behavior? I would have assumed that the soft start ramps up relatively slowly and would not require such high current peaks from the supply. Oscilloscope also shows that the output voltage raises almost instantly on the power-up.
It looks like that IC just draws about 4A current on startup. These oscilloscope captures demonstrate that with a lower current limit the bench supply cuts the voltage (with some delay).

If limit is 5A there is no problem as bench supply current limiter is not triggered.


‘Almost instantly’ - you’d want to measure that carefully! Everything takes a finite amount of time and time is of the essence here. You also need to consider how much input current is required to generate your 15V at  ~300mA. Also consider that connecting the module onto  a live output is akin to dropping the clutch in a car. If you connect the module to the psu, then power up the psu, what happens?

"Oscilloscope also shows that the output voltage raises almost instantly on the power-up." Please post oscillogram.

Do you have a schematic for the PCB? I found one on the internet MT3608, but I'm not sure it's the same module. Part of your inrush problem might be the 22 uF ceramic capacitor to the right of the IC, which appears to be directly connected to input+ and input-.
